# Determine this limit using L'Hopitals rule

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I couldn't find a way to get the answer for $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$$

From my knowledge of L'Hopital's Rule, I see that this is some kind of $1^{\infty}$ indeterminate form since I know from previous results that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=1$. Proceeded to find the limit of its natural $\log$ which is $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(
\frac{\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x})}{x^{2}}\right)$$ then got stuck when I got to $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(
\frac{\cot x-\frac{1}{x}}{2x}\right)$$ as I now get $\infty/0$ and this hasn't happened to me before since I just started not long ago on this topic. Can someone give me a further hint as to which direction I should head to or recommend me another more suitable approach to solve this problem?

If it helps, the given answer is $e^{-1/6}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor expansions?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I learnt from high school about Maclaurin expansions, I would think Taylor seems similar from what I looked up, but the university I'm in hasn't really covered it, so I think I'm expected to use L Hopital's rule to solve it.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth Try applying L'Hospitals one more time

Comment: Your fraction with $\cot$ in it is actually $0/0$, not $\infty/0$.

Comment: @GEdgar How so? $\tan x$ yields 0, so $\cot x$ gets $\infty$ and subtraction with another $\infty$ will get another $\infty$ in numerator

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth I think that if you saw that in high school, you shouldn't necessarily expect to see it again later. I added an answer using that method. It is arguable that you've used L'Hospital already.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth That is not necessarily true. If you look at the Taylor expansions (which I know may not be valid for the course thus far), you'll see that the first term in $\cot x$ is actually $\frac1x$ so the $\infty$ cancels out.

Comment: $\infty - \infty$ is indeterminate, so your numerator $\cot x - \frac{1}{x}$ needs some thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln \left(\frac {\sin x}{x} \right)}{x^2}$ has the form $\frac 00$ you apply L'Hospital's rule and investigate whether 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \frac{x}{\sin x} \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2}}{2x}$$ exists. But since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac x{\sin x} = 1$ it suffices to investigate
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{  \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2}}{2x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{2x^3}.$$ This has the form $\frac 00$ so apply L'Hospital again:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ -x \sin x + \cos x - \cos x}{6x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\sin x}{6x} = -\frac 16.$$

To recap, you can conclude
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{  \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2}}{2x} = -\frac 16$$
so that
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \frac{x}{\sin x} \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2}}{2x} = - \frac 16$$
and thus
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln \left(\frac {\sin x}{x} \right)}{x^2} = - \frac 16.$$

Comment: And this shows precisely the danger of simplifying too much at times :) +$1$

Comment: Wow, how does one think of adding in the factor of $x/\sin x$ though ... and is it a coincidence that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac x{\sin x} = 1=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin x}{x}$

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth: He didn't think of it... he just took the derivative of $\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x})$ and didn't simplify. As for the "coincidence" you ask about: it just follows from the continuity of $\frac{1}{x}$... that is, if $\lim f(x)=L\neq0$, then $\lim\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac1L$. I tried following where you got the rest of the way through (and I made progress), but it isn't nearly as clean as this.

Comment: @Clayton Oh ok my bad, was often rewarded for doing "clean work" back when I didn't take an entire module on calculus itself. Do u have tips for general in calculus, since I'm kinda new to it and obviously I have a high school to university gap to bridge after looking at this qns.

Answer (score 0):

$y=\lim _{x\to 0} \left(\dfrac{sinx}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{x^2}}$

$y=\lim _{x\to 0} \left(1+\dfrac{sinx-x}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{x^2}}$

$y=\lim _{x\to 0} \left[\left(1+\dfrac{sinx-x}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{x}{sinx-x}}\right]^{\dfrac{sinx-x}{x^3}}$

$y=\left(e^{\lim _{x\to 0}\dfrac{sinx-x}{x^3}}\right)$

now expand $sinx=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}-.......$

$y=e^{\frac{-1}{3!}}=e^{\dfrac{-1}{6}}$

QED

Comment: Hi, don't mind me asking, ur solution looks interesting, can u tell me how u got from line 3 to line 4 and somehow $(1+ \frac{\sin x-x}{x})^{\frac{x}{\sin x -x}}$ gets thrown out of the picture?

Comment: it is a standard limit formula $lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+kx\right)^{\dfrac{1}{x}}=e^{k}$

Comment: Alright, thanks for the information, I think I know how to improve my skills for L Hopital Rule